# JAXB Get namespace from non-root element?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-namespaces

Is there a way using JAXB to get the namespace programatically from a non-root element?

I can use the following on a root element (where Detailedreport is the root element object):

```
    QName qname = jaxb.getJaxbContext().createJAXBIntrospector().getElementName( new Detailedreport());
    final String namespace = qname.getNamespaceURI();
```

However, if I try using a type from the same package, but a non-root element, qname is null.

According to the [javadocs for JAXBIntrospector](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.html#getElementName(java.lang.Object)):

> Parameter object is a JAXB element for following cases:
>
> It is an instance of javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement. The class of object
>   is annotated with @XmlRootElement.

Given that my non-root element obviously doesn't have the @XmlRootElement, is there a way to get the qname/namespace for it?

Alternatively, is there a way to determine programtically which class represents the root element in a package (without having to scan all the classes myself for the annotation)?  I see the namespace in the package-info.java file, but not sure how to get at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I left the question here in case anyone else runs into the same question.

The namespace for the package is in the package-info.java file.  This information can be retrieved directly using java methods:

```
    String namespace = XmlElementName.class.getPackage().getAnnotation(XmlSchema.class).namespace();
```